# Is there a way to have a Maya python gui update with changes to settings in the rest of Maya?

Tags: user-interface, maya

I have a script that modifies the Maya render layers tab.  I was wondering if there was a way to have the floating UI update dynamically if the user changes render tab states and other things using the built in Maya interface. For instance, the render layers isted in the scripted tab would update if the user changes the render layers in the built in interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable but not trivial.

You'd use a [`scriptJob`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/scriptJob-html.html) to watch for changes and update your gui accordingly.

Some kinds of changes are exposed directly -- for example, you can react to the user changing the playback range with a scriptJob that reacts to a `playbackRangeChanged` event.  The docs page linked above includes the list of change events that can be listened for.

If you're watching for changes in attributes, you can use the `attributeChange` scriptJob type to run a script when a particular attribute is changed (by the UI or by anything else).  For example, this would print a message whenever the Persp camera's focal length changes:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def test():
    print "focal length:",  cmds.getAttr('perspShape.focalLength')

cmds.scriptJob(ac = ("perspShape.focalLength", test))
```

Other kinds of changes (the majority of them) are not available as predefined events.  You can sort of create your own events using the [`condition` command](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/), but you'll have to write the code which detects changes.  A lot of people simplify things by using a scriptjob that runs whenever Maya is idle and looks for changes.  That works, but you have to write it carefully because a complex script can slow Maya down a lot -- it will run whenever the user is not interacting with the UI.